Angular 17 SSR fetch failed error when making request to locahost ASP.Net Core Web API
This error happen whenever I refresh the page that make this http request.
The user.service.ts that return Observable from the API call.

  getUsers() {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('skip-loading', '');
    return this.http.get<PagedList<UserList>>(this.apiUrl + 'accounts/users/list', { headers });
  }


The method is call in OnInit in the component:

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loading = true;
    this.sub = this.userService.getUsers().subscribe({
      next: response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.users = response;
        this.data = response.data;
        this.loading = false;
        this.cdr.markForCheck();
      },
      error: err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }


The error interceptor catch the error and display toast message using toastr service as below:
enter image description here
Strange thing is when this error happen the toast message cannot be close.
The error interceptor implmentation as below:

  return next(req).pipe(
    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      // console.log('Error interceptor caught: ');
      // console.log(error);
      if(error) {
        switch(error.status) {
          case 0:
            //toastr.error('Server has encountered some unknown error, please try again.', 'Unknown Error');
            toastr.error(error.message, error.error);
            break;
          case 400: // Bad request (error - HttpErrorResponse).(error - object holder inside the response).(errors - Our API key validations messages)
            // If there is validation error, then we would like to give it to the origin to handle this
            if(error.error.errors) {
              throw error.error; // Throw to who ever want to handle this array
            } else {
                toastr.error(error.error.message, error.error.statusCode);
            }
            break;
          case 401:
            toastr.error(error.error.message, "Unauthorized Access");
            break;
          case 403:
            // Access defined error
            router.navigateByUrl('/404notfound');
            break;
          case 404:
            router.navigateByUrl('/404notfound');
            break;
          case 500:
            const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {state: {error: error.error}};
            router.navigateByUrl('/servererror', navigationExtras);
            break;
        }
      }

      return throwError(() => error);
    })
  );


The error is print out in the subscribe method above.
This is the error caught and output in the terminal, strange things is this does not show up on browser dev tool:
HttpErrorResponse {
  headers: _HttpHeaders {
    normalizedNames: Map(0) {},
    lazyUpdate: null,
    headers: Map(0) {}
  },
  status: 0,
  statusText: 'Unknown Error',
  url: 'https://localhost:7181/api/accounts/users/list',
  ok: false,
  name: 'HttpErrorResponse',
  message: 'Http failure response for https://localhost:7181/api/accounts/users/list: 0 undefined',
  error: TypeError: fetch failed
      at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11576:11)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    cause: Error: self-signed certificate
        at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1550:34)
        at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (c:/Users/Jsliew/source/repos/TribeBadmintonRankingSystem/ClientApp/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:403:31)
        at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (c:/Users/Jsliew/source/repos/packages/core/src/zone/async-stack-tagging.ts:46:22)
        at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (c:/Users/Jsliew/source/repos/TribeBadmintonRankingSystem/ClientApp/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:402:36)
        at Object.onInvokeTask (c:/Users/Jsliew/source/repos/packages/core/src/zone/ng_zone.ts:425:29)
        at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (c:/Users/Jsliew/source/repos/TribeBadmintonRankingSystem/ClientApp/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:402:36)
        at _Zone.runTask (c:/Users/Jsliew/source/repos/TribeBadmintonRankingSystem/ClientApp/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:174:47)
        at invokeTask (c:/Users/Jsliew/source/repos/TribeBadmintonRankingSystem/ClientApp/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:484:34)
        at TLSSocket.ZoneTask.invoke (c:/Users/Jsliew/source/repos/TribeBadmintonRankingSystem/ClientApp/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:473:48)
        at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:514:28) {
      code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'
    }
  }
}


Appreciate the help, thanks!
I have configure the CORS on the web api properly, this should not be the concern.
All these error will not appear when:

I build the project and run it with same domain of the Web API.
Disabled the SSR and client hydration of the project.


Do ngOninit() code inside ngAfterRender() or ngAfterNextRender(), These both lifecycle method will only run on client side. So, server side this api call will not called and only called when client side receive fully page. Try this once and see what happens.
